# How is Henry's constant affected by change in temperature

Tags: solutions

According to me Henry's constant $K_h$ should be directly proportional to the effect of temperature.

It is because $K_h$ is inversely proportional to solubility and as we increase temperature solubility decreases and hence $K_h$ value should increase.

But the correct answer is value of $K_h$ also decreases with increase in temperature.

Can anybody explain how?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law#Temperature_dependence) answers your question well. Also, solubility doesn't always increase with temperature.

Answer (score 0):

It is an application of the Le Chatelier principle. The dissolution of a gas in a solvant is exothermic. If you heat a system in equilibrium, where an exothermic reaction occurs, the system reacts by favoring the endothermic reaction. So at high temperature, the gas quits the liquid : the gas becomes less and less soluble in the solvant. The solubility of a gas in a solvant decreases with increase of temperature.